# Spark bulk load Solr from HDFS

Tags: solr, apache-spark, hdfs

There used to be a way to bulk load Solr from HDFS using MR jobs.  An old Doug Cutting video talks about it at 23:41
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5444z-L2V2A

I also took a screen shot of his slide below:

[image]

So you used to be able to read data from HDFS and write out multiple Solr shards...one per mapper.  How would I do something like this with Spark?  I found the Spark-Solr project by LucidWorks that has a SolrRDD, but it seems to do the writes to Solr using SolrJ.  I would like to just write out the shards into HDFS from a Spark RDD similar to what the MR job did.  How would I do this in Spark?